# html encryption issue to hide id and password true value

Tags: html, encryption

I got this kind of method for someone to login his/her account. I know it will be very good if I use php for this but running out of time to do that.
so, I was wondering if it is plausible to have those lines encrypted or only for the true values of id and password. BTW, I already tryied html encryption tool..

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="open.html">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading"><b> login Please </b></h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="daniel" autofocus="" />
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="dan89!"/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: and how you imagine browser will show your encrypted markup?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, and your HTML is invalid anyway. `required` is a boolean attribute.

Comment: oh sorry for my shortage.. how can I change this code then?

Comment: No idea. I don't understand what you are trying to do. (Unless you are asking the browser, which is completely under the control of the user, to verify that the user is who they claim they are … which is impossible).

Answer (score 0):

Every piece of code, which is on a client side should be considered as open and not secure. This is rule number one for any application.
If you need to hide something or encrypt something, do it on your server.
Even if you encrypt html you need to have the decryption key and algo somewhere on the page to decrypt it...so, this is really not the way forward.